# How to List SharePoint Groups in a dropdown list when uploading docs

Tags: document-library, custom-field-types

I would like to list all users and  SP groups in a dropdown list when uploading documents.I need this so i admins can select a specific group or users to assign permissions too.

Is this possible? I tried using the lookup column but didn't have the groups list.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: You can custom code it. Iterate through your `SPPrincipal`s and add each to a `DropDownList`. You'll also have to custom code the permissions assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list groups and users use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.groups.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allusers.aspx

Note that to be able to use the above APIs the user will need Enumerate permissions permission level.

To assign permissions, you will have to write custom code that creates roleassignments for each user selected and adds these assignments to the uniquely permissioned SPWeb or SPList or SPListItem as appropriate.